# Appending a Child to a Node Elsewhere in an XML Document

Tags: xml, vba

The following VBA code takes an XML file and appends a specific node to other nodes within the document:

```
Dim xmlFilePath$, newFilePath$
Dim DOM As MSXML2.DOMDocument
Dim Node As IXMLDOMNode
Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim itm As IXMLDOMNode

xmlfilepath = "Path"

newfilepath = "Path_2"

Set DOM = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")

DOM.Load xmlFilePath

For Each Node In DOM.DocumentElement.getElementsByTagName("Tag")
   For Each itm In Node.ParentNode.NextSibling.ChildNodes
            itm.appendChild Node.CloneNode(True)
    Next
Next

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set DOM = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
Set Node = Nothing

End Sub
```

This code works perfectly fine as written.  However, if the loop

```
For Each Node In DOM.DocumentElement.getElementsByTagName("Tag")
   For Each itm In Node.ParentNode.NextSibling.ChildNodes
            itm.appendChild Node.CloneNode(True)
    Next
Next
```

is changed to

```
For Each Node In DOM.DocumentElement.getElementsByTagName("Tag")
   For Each itm In Node.ParentNode.ParentNode
            itm.appendChild Node.CloneNode(True)
    Next
Next
```

I get an 'object required' error.  If I instead use `Node.ParentNode.ParentNode.ChildNodes` I get no error, but the node I am trying to append gets placed inside an already existing child node so that the result is something like `<a>Example<b>More_Writing</b></a>`.

Is there a way to have the path `Node.ParentNode.ParentNode` accepted as valid, or should I be approaching this a different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Node.ParentNode.ParentNode` will return a single node, not a collection, so you don't need the inner `For Each` loop :

```
For Each Node In DOM.DocumentElement.getElementsByTagName("Tag")
   Node.ParentNode.ParentNode.appendChild Node.CloneNode(True)
Next
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, that resolved the error, but for some reason nothing actually gets appended to the document with that replacement.

Comment: Create a variable to which you can assign `Node.ParentNode.ParentNode`, then add a Watch on that and do some debugging - is it what you expect?  Hard to tell exactly what's going on without sample XML.

Answer (score 0):

As Tim Williams provided the code which works fine. To resolve the problem with your XML not updating, you need to save your XML just like you have opened the XML

```
'Open XML
DOM.Load xmlFilePath

'Edit XML
For Each Node In DOM.DocumentElement.getElementsByTagName("Tag")
    Node.ParentNode.ParentNode.appendChild Node.CloneNode(True)
Next

'Save XML
Dom.Save xmlFilePath
```